# XSLT 1.0 Group Nodes by attribute value inside each element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

> I have XML like This

```
<root>
  <Users groupid="1">
    <User id="person1" name="ABC"  parentid="person7"/>
    <User id="person2" name="xyz"  parentid="person1"/>
    <User id="person3" name="LMN"  parentid="bac3"/>
    <User id="person4" name="PQR"  parentid="person2"/>
    <User id="person5" name="PQR" parentid="person1"/>
    <User id="person6" name="PQR" parentid="person7"/>
  </Users>
  <Users groupid="3">
    <User id="person7" name="ABC"  parentid="person11"/>
    <User id="person8" name="xyz"  parentid="person1"/>
    <User id="person3" name="LMN"  parentid="bac3"/>
    <User id="person4" name="PQR"  parentid="person2"/>
    <User id="person5" name="PQR" parentid="person1"/>
    <User id="person6" name="PQR" parentid="person7"/>
  </Users>
</root>
```

> I need to transform this using **xslt 1.0** to=>

```
<Users groupid="1">
  <User id="person1" name="ABC"  parentid="person7" haschildinGroup="yes"/>
      <User id="person2" name="xyz"  parentid="person1" haschildinGroup="yes"/>
          <User id="person4" name="PQR"  parentid="person2" haschildinGroup="no"/>
      <User id="person5" name="PQR" parentid="person1" haschildinGroup="no"/>
  <User id="person3" name="LMN"  parentid="bac3" haschildinGroup="no"/> 
  <User id="person6" name="PQR" parentid="person7" haschildinGroup="no"/>
</Users>
<Users groupid="3">
  <User id="person7" name="ABC"  parentid="person11" haschildinGroup="yes"/>
      <User id="person6" name="PQR" parentid="person7" haschildinGroup="no"/>
  <User id="person8" name="xyz"  parentid="person1" haschildinGroup="no"/>
  <User id="person3" name="LMN"  parentid="bac3" haschildinGroup="yes"/>
      <User id="person5" name="PQR" parentid="person3"  haschildinGroup="no"/>
  <User id="person4" name="PQR"  parentid="person2"  haschildinGroup="no"/>
</Users>
```

> **guide:** 1) i need to group the values based on the people who share parentid and above output xml explains more
>
> 2) need to put xml like indentation for parent child relation(adding extra spaces in the first) for HTML view
>
> I Tried Examples Like this but **Key** in this has scope on entire XML and
>   not within current Node

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>

      <xsl:key name="groups" match="User" use="@parentid" />
      <xsl:variable name="Space">&amp;nbsp;</xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="addSpace" select="concat($Space,$Space)"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <xsl:for-each select="root/Users/User[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('groups',@parentid)[1])]">
              <xsl:call-template name="selectusers"></xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </table>
        </html>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="selectusers">
          <xsl:for-each select="key('groups', @parentid)">
            <tr>
               <xsl:value-of select="$addSpace" disable-output-escaping="yes"/><!--Works for only 1st Level need to add If-->
              <td>

                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <!--HasChild =:(-->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSLT is written to generate HTML instead of what you have described as your desired output, but I will assume that what you want is actually the HTML you were trying to produce. If so, this should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:key name="groups" match="User" use="concat(../@groupid, '+', @parentid)" />
  <xsl:variable name="Space">&#xA0;</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="addSpace" select="concat($Space,$Space)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Has Children</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates 
              select="root/Users/User[not(@parentid = ../User/@id)]" />
      </table>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="User">
    <xsl:variable name="children"
                  select="key('groups', concat(../@groupid, '+', @id))" />

    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="spacing" />
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring('No Yes', 1 + 3 * boolean($children), 3)"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$children" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="User" mode="spacing">
    <xsl:value-of select="$addSpace" />
    <xsl:apply-templates 
          select="../User[@id = current()/@parentid]" mode="spacing" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<html>
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Has Children</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  person1</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>    person2</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>      person4</td>
      <td>No </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>    person5</td>
      <td>No </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  person3</td>
      <td>No </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  person6</td>
      <td>No </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  person7</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>    person6</td>
      <td>No </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  person8</td>
      <td>No </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  person3</td>
      <td>No </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  person4</td>
      <td>No </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  person5</td>
      <td>No </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes you got me right. Just to explain clearly i gave that output XML.
Accepting the answer :)
Thanks

Comment: Quick question is there any problem if i use call template instead of apply template because i need integrate this in the middle of somewhere

Comment: `call-template` and `apply-templates` are considerably different and not really interchangeable.  If you can open up another question showing where you need this integrated, we can show you how to do it.